# How can I select the 10 largest values from three different columns and save them in a new data frame in R?

Tags: r

```
Var1 <- 90:115
Var2 <- 1:26
Var3 <- 52:27

data <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

Hi, I want to select from each column the 10 largest values and save them in a new data frame?  I know that in my example the new data frame will contain 20 rows but I don't understand the correct workflow.

That's what I'm expecting:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
90    1    52
91    2    51
92    3    50
93    4    49
94    5    48
95    6    47
96    7    46
97    8    45
98    9    44
99    10   43
106   17   36
107   18   35
108   19   34
109   20   33
110   21   32
111   22   31
112   23   30
113   24   29
114   25   28
115   26   27
```

I can solve my problem for three column with this approach

```
df <- subset(data, Var1 >=106 | Var2 >=17 | Var3 >=43)
```

but if I have to do that for 50+ columns it's not really the best solution.

Comment: I am confused, since the output that you say you are expecting is already stored in your initial frame `data`, so I'm not sure what the expected output is. What do you mean by 'top 10 values'? Those which are on the top of the data frame, or those with the largest values?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Your approach with the `subset` gets ore than 10 rows.

Comment: Can you explain if you want top 10 values from each column, how can the new data frame contain 20 rows?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's about the largest values.

Comment: Neither 107 or 17 or 43 are the largest value in the dataset columns

Comment: @akrun You can see my expected output in my question.

Comment: If you don't want to break the order within the rows, you probably need to define a rule which value should be sorted, like, e.g., the largest sum of each row.

Comment: @cosmin I had seen that, but it is not what you asked in the title (top 10 is not top 20).  Also, it is just the initial dataset...

Comment: @akrun I understand you point. I'll change the title of my question.

Comment: With the edit the problem becomes clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
data[sort(unique(c(sapply(data,order,decreasing=T)[1:10,]))),]
```

Basically index the top 10 elements from each column, merge them and remove duplicate, reorder and extract it from the original data.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by looping over the columns with `lapply`, `sort` them, and get the first 10 values with `head`

```
 data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) head(sort(x, 
                           decreasing=TRUE) ,10)))
```

If we need the first 10 rows, just use

```
 head(data, 10)
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's edit

```
data[sort(Reduce(union,lapply(data, function(x) 
                  order(x,decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]))),]
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the confusion .

Comment: @cosmin It's okay.  Glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer to your question:

```
nv1 <- sort(Var1,decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]
nv2 <- sort(Var2,decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]
nv3 <- sort(Var2,decreasing = TRUE)[1:10]
nd <- data.frame(nv1, nv2, nv3)
```

But why would you want to do such a thing?  You're breaking the order of the data -- Var3 is increasing and the others are decreasing.  Perhaps you want a list, rather than a data frame?

Comment: That's the point. Your examples here break the order of the data. I need a solution that won't break the structure. That's why I'm expecting a table with 20 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
thresh <- sapply(data,sort,decreasing=T)[10,]
data[!!rowSums(sapply(1:ncol(data),function(x) data[,x]>=thresh[x])),]
```

First, a vector `thresh` is defined, which contains the tenth largest value of each column. Then we perform a loop over the columns to check if any of the values is larger than or equal to the corresponding threshold value. The `!!` is a shorthand notation for `as.logical()`, which (owing to the combination with `rowSums`) selects those rows where at least one of the values is above or equal to the threshold. In your example this yields the output:

```
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    90    1   52
#2    91    2   51
#3    92    3   50
#4    93    4   49
#5    94    5   48
#6    95    6   47
#7    96    7   46
#8    97    8   45
#9    98    9   44
#10   99   10   43
#17  106   17   36
#18  107   18   35
#19  108   19   34
#20  109   20   33
#21  110   21   32
#22  111   22   31
#23  112   23   30
#24  113   24   29
#25  114   25   28
#26  115   26   27
```

Which is equal to the output that you obtain with the command you posted:

```
#> identical(data[!!rowSums(sapply(1:ncol(data),function(x) data[,x]>=thresh[x])),], subset(data, Var1 >=106 | Var2 >=17 | Var3 >=43))
[1] TRUE
```